# Unhandled Exception of Type System.Data.SqlClient SQL Exception in System.Data.dll

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am attempting to code a little Customer/sales database in VB. However on compiling I am getting the error stated in the subject. Apparently there is no connection to the database posible.

Here is the code I got so far:

```
Public Class Principal
Using Connect As SqlConnection = 
Friend Sub CreateDatabase()
New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);" & 
"Integrated Security='SSPI';")

Dim strCreateDatabase As String = "IF EXISTS ( " & 
"SELECT name " &
"FROM sys.databases " & 
"WHERE name = N'BMSTIDB'" &
" ) " & 
"DROP DATABASE BMSTIDB; " & 
"CREATE DATABASE BMSTIDB" 

Dim Command As SqlCommand = 
New SqlCommand(strCreateDatabase, Connect) 

Connect.Open() 
Connect.ExecuteNonQuery() 

MsgBox("A Database with the name of " & 
"BMSTIDB has been created. ")
End Using
```

It compiles fine and it doens't display any errors or issues. However as mentioned above it does give the error upon running, when it first attempts to connect to the DB.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and Community.

Thanks a lot,

BenjB

Comment: You tagged this "mysql", but those are Sql Server connection strings and SqlCommand/SqlConnection types. You need completely different connection stings and data access objects to talk to MySql.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Edited and added some other change I made.

Comment: It's still not clear what database engine you're using. This is a big deal, and you should put the right tag on the question.

Comment: Still pretty new here and your advice is much appreciated. I am working on visual studio 2015 and for now I am just attempting to connect to a local database, following a tutorial I found on a different site and modified it a bit...

Answer (score 0):

```
New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);" &
```

"Integrated Security='SSPI';**Database=master**")

Comment: @f0r3v3r-A-Noob Thanks for the quick reply. I have added `code` "Integrated Security='SSPI'; Database=master") `code` It does give the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing single quote here:

```
"WHERE name = N'BMSTIDB" &
```

It should be:

```
"WHERE name = N'BMSTIDB'" &
```

Once you fix that you'll find you're also missing the `BEGIN` and `END` keywords.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that one. The error still persists and remains the same though. I have also tried to change `(local)` to `(localDB)` without success.

Comment: are you able to connect to the database via sql server management studio?